# How do you use "WHERE x IN y" clauses with clojure/java.jdbc?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, clojure

I am trying to get a simple DB query working, but I can't get `clojure/java.jdbc` to select from an `IN` clause.

The code looks like this:

```
(sql/with-connection db
  (sql/with-query-results rows
    ["select  f.name        name
          ,   f.id          file_id
      from    FileCategory  fc
      join    File          f
          on  fc.file       = f.id
      where   fc.category   in ?
      having  count(1)      >= ?"
     [1 2]    ; This is the bit which does not work.
              ; I have tried (to-array) and (set) too
     2]
    (into [] rows)))
```

Any Ideas as to how I may pass the set to the query?

Running the query directly under `mysql` I get no problems:

```
mysql> select f.name, f.id from FileCategory fc join File f on fc.file = f.id where fc.category in (1, 2) having count(1) >= 2;
+-----------+----+
| name      | id |
+-----------+----+
| some name |  1 |
+-----------+----+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

In case it makes a difference I'm using: org.clojure/clojure 1.4.0, org.clojure/java.jdbc 0.2.3 and mysql/mysql-connector-java 5.1.6.

Comment: You can't do this with prepared statements. Well, you can use `WHERE in (?, ?) HAVING count(1) >= ?` with `1 2 2` as data arguments. But not like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```clj
(sql/with-connection db
  (sql/with-query-results rows
    ["select  f.name        name
          ,   f.id          file_id
      from    FileCategory  fc
      join    File          f
          on  fc.file       = f.id
      where   fc.category   in (?, ?)
      having  count(1)      >= ?"
     1 2 2]
    (into [] rows)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the number of items in the list is variable. The second parameter is it's count.

Comment: @dsm I see, you need to dynamically create the proper amount of `?` in the string then

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping it wouldn't come to that though.

Comment: @dsm yeah too bad.. You can use this for generating `n` question marks separated with `,`: `(clojure.string/join ", " (take n (repeat "?")))`

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL you must generate a SQL query with the correct number of '?' unfortunately.

You may find that working at a higher level of abstraction works better. eg. your query in [korma](http://sqlkorma.com/) looks like this:

```clj
(defentity file)
(defentity filecategory)

(def categories ["movie" "tv" "news"])

(as-sql (select file
       (fields :name :file_id)
       (join filecategory (= :file.id :filecategory.file))
           (where { :filecategory.category [in categories]} )
       (having (> (sqlfn :count 1) 1))))

; SELECT `file`.`name`, `file`.`file_id` FROM `file` LEFT JOIN 
;        `filecategory` ON `file`.`id` = `filecategory`.`file` 
;         WHERE (`filecategory`.`category` IN (?, ?, ?)) 
;         HAVING COUNT(?) > ?  ::  [tv movie news 1 1]
```

You can tidy this up further by moving the FK declarations into the `defentity` calls if desired.